# A CROSS JOIN with a RIGHT JOIN

Tags: postgresql, join, cross-join

I have a table "typl" containing only 2 values :

```
typl 
------
 COL
 IND
```

and a table "store" with 2 columns:

```
achl | typl 
------+------
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 BBBB | COL
 BBBB | COL
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
```

The problem : I can find a query where, for a set of achl in the store table, if there's only one typl like for achl='AAAA', all the lines will be cross joined with the "typl" table, so the result will be :

```
achl | typl 
------+------
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | COL
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 AAAA | IND
 BBBB | COL
 BBBB | COL
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
 BBBB | IND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/933cd3/1)

```
select *
from (
    select achl, typl
    from store
    union all
    select achl, t.typl
    from store s cross join typl t
    where (achl, t.typl) not in (
        select achl, typl
        from store
    )
) s
order by achl, typl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM store 
WHERE achl IN (
    SELECT achl 
    FROM store
    GROUP BY achl
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT typl) = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not the exact answer for my question but it gives me the way to achieve the problem.